# Searching for the commit where a code was updated in public Git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have an issue where some functionalities were deprecated in latest updates of a Python library, and I am looking to test whether rolling back to an earlier version may work. However, I am unfamiliar with version control systems like Git and could use some pointers on how to navigate it to find the information I am looking for.

Specifically, I am looking on Github for this [public repository](https://github.com/keras-team/keras), and this [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py).

In the latest `master` branch, the following warning was added to indicate deprecation of a feature:

```
if K.backend() == 'theano' and (dropout or recurrent_dropout):
            warnings.warn(
                'RNN dropout is no longer supported with the Theano backend '
                'due to technical limitations. '
```

How can I find when (and what version of the library) this line was added in the file? I've stumbled across a History tab on the Git source code, but all I could manage to find was this [commit](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/2c9b7d0dd8ffeb906c291a087c25c40fb8c7788e#diff-3118e4e28157032506f771f279a551c3) which implies that the feature must've been deprecated prior to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can blame the file from github:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blame/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py

You can do the exact same thing on git, just in case.

And https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/dec0c7b7aeddab2b31b55ccb015d7e0735206d59 you can see that it has been in python since 2.1.3? (checking the tags)

Comment: Awesome! Found what I'm looking for: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/8660